# How would I go about fixing SyntaxError: Unexpected token, as it suddenly pops up?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I was typing a Discord bot, and then right as I executed the command, I got SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' I want to know, where exactly did I go wrong? This is my code

v

````
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-d'

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('DaveBot is online!');
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(-d) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    }
});

client.login('bot token, censored so it doesn't get taken');```
````

Comment: Syntax highlighting here shows you that the last line is broken. It's surrounded with single quotes but you also used a single quote within, thus terminating it early. You need to surround it in double quotes.

Comment: @VLAZ in the original code it has a login token though, the string there is only a placeholder for posting on SO. On Chrome entering just the last line gives a different error anyway: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this:

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(-d) || message.author.bot) return;
```

should be this:

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
```

The issue is that `-d` is interpreted as the negative of `d` which is undefined, you probably meant either `prefix` or `"-d"` in quotes.

Comment: This would be a ReferenceError, rather than a SyntaxError.

Comment: @VLAZ yes, if that's the only code present. But given the error is not a ReferenceError there is presumably a variable `d` defined somewhere else. It looks like the syntax error in question is not in the code listed.